# Getting the selected row from a ASP.Net FormView bound to ObjectDataSource in the ItemUpdating event

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, objectdatasource, formview

I have to maintain an ASP.net application in VB.Net.
There is a page with a FormView bound to a ObjectDataSource.

I have to add some business logic on the ItemUpdating event of this FormView.

Unfortunately, some the data that I need to add this business logic is not exposed on the FormView user-interface itself, so I can not use FindControl to get the values (I could add the controls, bind them to the fields I need and set their visible property to true, but that's ugly).

So, what I would need to do is to get access to the Data Row corresponding to the currently selected item in the FormView from the code behind as it has the data I need to add my business logic code.

Unfortunately, I don't manage to get access to the row.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Thanks, I managed to sort it using the Select method of the ObjectDataSource object.
This returned me a DataView containing the row that was currently being edited.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Dim myData As Object = DirectCast(formview1.DataItem, DataRowView)("MyColumn")
```

EDIT:
If I remember correctly the DataItem is Nothing on ItemUpdating  so my solution above does not work, does it? Then you have to load it from your Datasource with the given ID(CommandArgument).